# stream bytearray to server using flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can easily send  bytearray to server using these codes :

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_var1);
req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = DATAS;   
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
```

in this data , DATAS is a bytearray , and it is ready, but I want to send byterray that is generated live and have not length in fact .

I want to stream bytearray , How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Socket connection:

```
    var socket:Socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(host, port);
    socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, function(event:Event):void
    {
        socket.writeBytes(DATAS);
    });
```

UPD for the test code for the comments:

```
    var _buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    _buffer.writeByte(0xFF);
    trace("_buffer=",ByteArrayUtil.getHexBytesString(_buffer));

    var ou:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    ou.writeBytes(_buffer , 0 ,_buffer.length);
    _buffer.clear();        

    trace("ou=\t", ByteArrayUtil.getHexBytesString(ou));
    trace("_buffer=", ByteArrayUtil.getHexBytesString(_buffer));


public static function getHexBytesString(array:ByteArray, colons:Boolean=false, position:int = 0, len:int = 0):String {
    var s:String = "";
    if(!array)
        return s;

    if(len)
    {
        len += position;
        len = Math.min(len, array.length);
    }
    else
        len = array.length;

    for (var i:int=position;i<len;i++) {
        s+=("0"+array[i].toString(16)).substr(-2,2).toUpperCase();
        if (colons && i<len-1) s+= "-";
    }
    return s;
}
```

output:

```
_buffer= FF
ou=  FF
_buffer=
```

Comment: @fsbmin : also I want to copy some byte array to another byte array and make first byte array clear, but in unexpected result , when I clear bytearray one , bytearray two will became empty , do you know where is the problem ? ::::  var ou:ByteArray = new ByteArray();ou.writeBytes(_buffer , 0 ,_buffer.length);_buffer.position = 0;_buffer.clear();

Comment: I don't have this problem with your code, _ou_ byte array doesn't cleared. May be your buffer is empty from the beginning. I updated me answer with the test.

Comment: yes , yes, the problem was from me, very thanks , you have nice knowledge on flash , thanks